# React-Bootstrap Navbar is not sticking at the footer

Tags: css, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a problem fixing the navbar to the bottom of the page. I need it to appear only when the page reaches the end, not that it stays fixed on the page.

I am using the Navbar component of react-bootstrap (https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/navbar/).

Here is a gist with an example:
https://gist.github.com/fredarend/5f6c30d600a37faf9e4f983da0133e31

The navbar has the option "sticky = bottom", however, it is not placed at the bottom.

Comment: Use fixed="bottom" then. And then in will be always fixed to the bottom even when scrolling.

Comment: I expressed myself badly, I edited the question. Sorry, my english writing is not good.

Comment: You need to set the height of the parent (of the navbar) to 100% and the navbar it self should have a style: top: 0 and then the sticky will work. The reason is that sticky doesn't work if there is not height specified.

Comment: updated the gist, inserted the global styles, the parent of the navbar is the body. It is with height: 100%.